Linux Freezes randomly after waking up from suspend
Hello linux fellas.
I'm currently using Fedora 40 with SwayFX as a compositor, swayidle as an idle manager and gtklock as a screen locker, on my Lenovo ThinkPad T460. I also use TLP.
This issue happens randomly, it goes as follows:

The laptop wakes up from suspend.

Trackpoint and Thinkpad's touchpad buttons don't work.

After some short while (from 10 seconds to about a minute) the laptop just freezes, keyboard, touchpad, nothing responds. The only way to get out of it is to force shutdown the laptop.


As I said the issue happens randomly, so sometimes it wakes up just fine, sometimes this happens.
Here are my Laptop specs of someone needs it:
CPU: Intel Core I5 6300U
GPU: Intel HG Graphics 520
RAM: 8GB
Storage: 256GB SSD
Any help appreciated.
EDIT: I have this after entering sudo dmesg -w | grep psmouse
[    1.698006] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5676], y [..4758]
[    1.732251] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1096..]
[    1.732303] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: LEN2016 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
[    1.797434] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.2, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xf006a3/0x943300/0x12e800/0x10000, board id: 3053, fw id: 2010421
[    1.797483] psmouse serio1: synaptics: serio: Synaptics pass-through port at isa0060/serio1/input0
[    2.470891] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[ 2230.792723] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5676], y [..4758]
[ 2230.822891] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1096..]
[ 2231.693170] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[ 2232.214818] psmouse serio2: Failed to deactivate mouse on synaptics-pt/serio0: -5
[ 2247.273097] psmouse serio2: Failed to disable mouse on synaptics-pt/serio0
[ 2248.597932] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5676], y [..4758]
[ 2248.628580] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1096..]
[ 2478.144893] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5676], y [..4758]
[ 2478.174896] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1096..]
[ 2508.026712] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5676], y [..4758]
[ 2508.066967] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1096..]

hope this helps.

Resume the laptop, login into your laptop via SSH remotely, run sudo dmesg -f, post the messages that appear on the screen the last just before it freezes. If nothing shows up, that could indicate a HW issue. Linux just doesn't freeze for no reasons.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov Let me try this, thank you.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov -f flag requires an argument, what to give it?

Sorry, I meant -w or --follow.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov what kind of error do I have to see? Should I see something trackpoint or touchpad related?

@ArtemS.Tashkinov I've put the output into the post, please check.

Why did you grep? I needed full output, not just your mouse log. It's very unlikely that it can cause a kernel panic.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov full log is too long I thought, and the issue part seems to stem from psmouse, since it is the one throwing errors and warnings
I could not find anything concerning about any other log in dmesg, but if you consider it to be needed, then let me replicate the issue again.

I managed to solve the issue (at least haven't encountered such problem thus far since then) by adding psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=1 into the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX= field in the /etc/default/grub file and then entering a following command:
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
This seems to create new issue though, sometimes when turning laptop on or rebooting it just boots into black screen forever until I force shut it and turn on back again. But at least this current issue is solved, I guess I need to submit a bug report on this to the kernel (as the log states).

I would start to check by following:

boot by Linux bootstick like debian or LMDE6 and check 10 minutes the pc is working well. So you get a good first hit about its a software or a hardware problem. If the problem not happen, it should be a software or a harddisk problem.

If the system also freeze by useing bootstick, I would test the memory by software like Memtest86+ v6 (is a unified, free, open-source memory testing tool, released under GNU GPL v2.0).

A good source for information also can be to check error logg. It should be to enlarge the error logging on some systems a little bit.

Also a good way is, to check your RAM and later your SSD on a other known working System by testing software.



This happened with Ubuntu and OpenSUSE as well, so I don't know whether I need to test it with a liveCD
